# How to add an HTML web browser window in an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with data.

I retrieve the data and create an image through 3js and it will create an html file.

When I open that html file on a button click from Excel it renders a browser window and shows it there.

I want the browser window to appear embedded on the Excel worksheet I am working on.

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776555/using-html-as-a-interface-for-vba-excel

Comment: doesn't answer my question. not even related, sir. but thanks anyways :)

Comment: if you wanted to learn that was the right place for you to start but any way here is the code just copy and past and rename controls to what you have

Comment: did the later solve your problem if it did please mark it as your answer

Comment: It didn't but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you have to put the  Microsoft Web Browser control on your spread sheet or form and on your code open the file using this control like so;

```
     Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate "H:\folder in your pc\test.html" '"http://www.google.com"
     End Sub
```

Comment: It is giving me "Cannot insert object"   @Tim

Comment: please explain  what you are doing

Comment: I am trying to insert a Microsoft Web Browser Control in my Excel 2017 worksheet from the Insert button in the Developer Tools. Just when I draw the Web Browser Control, it is showing me "Cannot Insert Object"